# Is there any reason to use @type for private variables with advanced compilation?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

JSDoc documentation says JSDoc is only used for generating API documentation, but we also use advanced compilation using Google's Closure Compiler

In a function scope, we have many strings eg

`var cssLeft, cssTop, cssWidth, cssHeight, cssMinWidth, cssMinHeight, cssMaxWidth,
            cssMaxHeight, cssTransform;`

Is there any reason to include `@type {string}` for each of these vars?

Comment: jsdoc is used to decorate *exposed API members*, not local variables.

Comment: Anyway, Closure Compiler is *not* jsdoc but it uses syntax 'quite close' to that of jsdoc, such that they are mostly compatible; consult it's documentation to see what optimizations it can perform for the different tags, if any. Again I suspect it is not relevant for local variables (jsdoc-proper will not even read such tags), but see the Closure Compiler documentation.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tag-type

Answer (score 1):

For JSDoc, there is no need since the variables aren't exposed.

For Google Closure Compiler, defining the type can't hurt, and could possibly speed things up and/or minify the resulting code

The reason for using @type: there's no reason not to

Answer (score 1):

The Closure Compiler will generally infer the type of a local variable if the value type is known.  Declaring the type of a value makes it possible for the compiler to tell you if the value is of an unexpected type when the value is assigned.   If you aren't reassigning the EcmaScript 6 "const" is preferred or alternately simply @const:

```
/** @const */ var x = ...
```

Note that the Closure Compiler also supports "inline" type syntax if decide you want to declare the type:

```
var /** string */ x = ..., /** string */ y = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

By experience when you specify the visibility you get a more concise and advanced compilation error checking during compilation time.

From closure compiler Doc
Marks a member as private. 
 Only code in the same file can access global variables and functions marked @private.
 Constructors marked @private can only be instantiated by code in the same file and by their static and instance members.

The public static properties of constructors marked @private may also be accessed anywhere, and the instanceof operator can always access @private members.

For example:

> /**  * Handlers that are listening to this logger. 
>  * @private
>   {Array}  */ this.handlers_ = [];

More info here https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler